# Updating variable without printing new lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

i am running this program to let me know if this ip address is down or up.
the problem that i have is that it constantly prints new lines instead i want it to just show 1 line and every time it updates so if it goes off on the same line it goes from online to offline on the same line. How do i do that

```
import os

ip = "192.168.2.1"

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

while True:

    exit_code = os.system("ping -n 1 -w 1 " + ip + " > nul") # Windows

    if exit_code == 0:
        print("status " + bcolors.OKGREEN + "ONLINE " + bcolors.ENDC)

    else:
        print("status " + bcolors.FAIL + "OFFLINE" + bcolors.ENDC)
```

what i get:

```
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
status ONLINE
```

Comment: Can you include an example of your DESIRED output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a carriage return to the `end` parameter to print. This should do it I think.

`print("status " + bcolors.OKGREEN + "ONLINE " + bcolors.ENDC, end='\r')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `end` and return carriage `\r`

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    print("same line \r",end='')
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
same line
```